# Angular directive memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

I'm using this simple html file to reproduce a memory leak I found:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

            app.directive('directive1', function() {
                return {
                    template: '<div directive2></div>',
                    scope: true
                };
            });

            app.directive('directive2', function () {
                function LeakObject() {}

                function Foo() {
                    this.bar = function($scope) {
                            $scope.nottheredude;
                    };
                }

                return {
                    scope: true,
                    link: function($scope) {
                            $scope.memoryThatLeaks = new LeakObject();

                            new Foo().bar({});
                            new Foo().bar($scope);
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="testApp">
        <button ng-click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
        <div ng-if="show">The directive <div directive1></div></div>
        <div ng-if="!show">Nothing</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a directive that only creates a new scope and has another directive in its template.

The other directive does something a bit strange (I tried to narrow down the problem to what's causing the leak and that's the shortest code I found that reproduces the issue).

In my main html, I just toggle between nothing and `directive1` with a simple `ng-if`.

Notice that `directive2` also creates a new object on the `$scope` called `LeakObject`. I expect this object to be garbage collected when I'm toggling back to the nothing div, since the scope of the directive should die and all the data on it with it, but according to Chrome's heap snapshot tool in incognito mode, it's not getting unallocated.

I'm trying to understand why that happens, and why, if I comment out the statement in the `bar` method, it doesn't happen.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1567751/ravello-bug/index.html) in incognito
2. Open dev tools and go to Profiles
3. Refresh the page
4. Click `Toggle` twice (so now you see `Nothing` on the screen again)
5. Take a heap snapshot
6. Write 'leak' in the filter so you can see the `LeakObject` still exists when it shouldn't really exist.

This is how it should look like:

[image: The problem]

Can someone please help/explain?

Comment: Apparently, this is not an issue in Windows 8, Chrome 42

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on Ubuntu15/Chome

Answer (score 2):

Everything works as expected,
after following your steps i don't see any leak objects in the snapshot.

you can add the following code to the link function to see that the directive is actually getting destroy

Controller and directives emit an event right before they are destroyed. This is where you are given the opportunity to tear down your plugins and listeners and pretty much perform garbage collection.
Subscribe to the $scope.$on('$destroy', ...) event

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
  //$scope.memoryThatLeaks = null;
  alert('!');
 });
```

Comment: So you're saying you can't reproduce the problem, maybe it's a OS/browser issue.
I', running on Chrome 39.0.2171.71 on OSX Yosemite, it also happens to other devs I spoke to.
I know the directive is being destroyed, that's why it seems like a memory leak.

Comment: The fact that the function passed to `$on('$destroy'` gets executed doesn't really prove that the directive is getting "destroyed" nor that there isn't a memory leak. Not saying there is a memory leak though, haven't looked into it myself.

Comment: you are right, the fact that '$destroy' event is fired prove that Angular's flow is working as expected, the directive and it scope should be deleted.

Comment: i think that the lines new Foo().bar({});
                            new Foo().bar($scope);
creates objects on global, that probably be the cause to the leak.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1. Why would it create it on global scope? 2. I don't think it's the case since adding the line `new Foo().bar({})` again will stop the leak...

Comment: @Moran "*"the fact that '$destroy' event is fired prove that Angular's flow is working as expected, the directive and it scope should be deleted"* - if there is a leak, even though `'$destroy'` is fired, the GC won't be able to collect the directive and it's scope, that is what a leak is.